# Publishing a custom domain website using Carrd.co and AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, custom-domain

I'm trying to publish a custom-domain website using carrd.co and AWS route 53. I think I have saved the host records correctly but I am not entirely sure.

For some reason, the domain isn't resolving to anything.

Comment: Hi there, generally stack overflow is a place to have `questions` answered, yet you don't appear to be asking a question here. Could you work out what your trying to find out, and then edit your post to include your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you followed the Carrd instructions and added A records with the host set as '@' with the targets as the listed IP addresses.

For Route53, you don't have to put in the '@'. Simply leave the host blank and input the targets (IP addresses) and save. Give it some time and it will work!